# Android, set Background Stretches or zooms in but never correct

Tags: java, android, wallpaper

I have currently been trying to set a background of my phone using an android wallpaper app that i made. However every time i press "Set background" it stretches the image.

Here is the code that i am using

```
btnSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                WallpaperManager wManager;

                try {

                    //  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(view.getContext().getApplicationContext());

                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int fullWidth = size.x;
                    int fullHeight = size.y;

                    //int fullWidth   = wManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
                    //int fullHeight  = wManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();

                    Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullWidth));
                    Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullHeight));

                    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpWallpaper, fullWidth * 2, fullHeight, true);
                    wManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Core.makeNotification(view.getContext(), "MyNotification", "Your wallpaper has been set, enjoy!");
                Core.makeAlert(view.getContext(), "Wallpaper set", "Your wallpaper has been set, enjoy!");

            }
        });
```

Comment: y r u doing `fullWidth * 2` ?

Comment: Someone told me that works but it didnt work, it also doesn't work if i remove the *2

Comment: what is the the size of the bitmap..scaling a bitmap smaller than the phone's screen will stretch..

Comment: the size is exactly the same as the phone i am using (sgs3) however the background is zoomed if take the prefered dimensions from the wallpaper manager and is stretched when i take the phone dimensions

Comment: check if [this](http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/set-wallpaper/) link helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot, after combining some opf my code with the code described there i got a working solution

Answer (score 2):

Okay after the comment from bakriOnFire i searched around on the link he gave me, after combining a bit of my code with the code described there i've found a solution!

```
 btnSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    WallpaperManager wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(view.getContext());

                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int fullWidth = size.x;
                    int fullHeight = size.y;

                    //int fullWidth   = wManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
                    //int fullHeight  = wManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();

                    Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullWidth));
                    Log.d("Debug", Integer.toString(fullHeight));


                    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpWallpaper, fullWidth, fullHeight, true);
                    wManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(bitmapResized.getWidth(), bitmapResized.getHeight());

                    wManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Core.makeNotification(view.getContext(), "MCPaper", "Your wallpaper has been set, enjoy!");
                Core.makeAlert(view.getContext(), "Wallpaper set", "Your wallpaper has been set, enjoy!");

            }
        });
```

I really hope that in the future this well help people out because i've spend a long time on this. enjoy